# Renaming rails json api keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller as follows:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class SpacesController < ApplicationController            
            before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
            respond_to :json
                        def index
                respond_with Space.all
            end

        end
    end
```

now this returns the following json

```
{
   "id":2,
   "home_type":"Rental",
   "room_count":1,
   "listing_name":"test",
   "summary":{
      "id":2,
      "name":"summary",
      "body":"<div>great</div>",
      "record_type":"Space",
      "record_id":2,
      "created_at":"2020-07-06T16:13:41.279Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-07-06T16:14:00.926Z"
   },
   "address":"undefined",
   "price":900,
   "security_deposit":900,
   "active":true,
   "user_id":1,
   "created_at":"2020-07-06T16:13:35.877Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-07-06T16:14:13.258Z",
   "square_foot":32,
   "move_in_date":"2020-07-23",
   "slug":"undefined",
   "other_expenses":"No",
   "floor":2,
   "floors":4,
   "pets":true
}
```

suppose I would like to change the name of let's say "home_type" to "homeType". How should I do this without generating a migration or changing the actual column name?

Comment: I am assuming you are looking for Camel Case for all keys. If so I would create a "helper method" in `ApplicationRecord` to handle the transition via `def camel_case_json(options={}); as_json(options).deep_transform_keys {|k| k.to_s.camelize };end`. If you want this to be the json representation all the time then you should be able to change this to `def as_json(options={}); super(options).deep_transform_keys {|k| k.to_s.camelize };end`

Comment: Ah, apologies for the bad communication. I'm not actually looking for Camel casing the keys, that was just for the example! @engineersmnky

Comment: this article is worth a read too: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
hash[:homeType] = hash.delete :home_type
```

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on how would I go about this with the controller I currently have set up, since I'm using `Space.all`?